# Import csv file using pandas and split the resulting strings

Tags: python, csv, pandas, import

I want to read this [csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qzlx3pndb260cd/report.csv?dl=0) in pandas as a DataFrame. Then I would like to split the resulting strings from colons.

I import using:

```
df_r = pd.read_csv("report.csv", sep=";|,", engine="python")
```

Then split using:

```
for c in df_r:
    if df_r[c].dtype == "object":
        df_r[c] = df_r[c].str.split(':')
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"\x001\x000\x00'
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**Edit:**

The error actually shows when I try to convert one of the strings to a float

```
print(float(df_r["Laptime"].iloc[0][2]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and everything works fine. You can try catching the error and print the row that has that strange behaviour and manual inspect that.

Is that the entire dump you are using? I saw that you are assigning the csv to the variable `a` and using `df_r` afterwards so I think you are doing something else in between.

If the csv file is complete be aware that the last line is empty and create a row full of NaNs. You want to read the csv with `skipfooter=1`.

```
a = pd.read_csv('report.csv', sep=";|,", engine="python", skipfooter=1)
```

**Edit**:
You can convert it to float like this:

```
print(float(df_r["Laptime"].iloc[0][2].replace(b'\x00',b'')))
```

Comment: I did not correctly ask my question at first. I made an edit. That error shows when I try to convert one of the string to a float. Would you please check that out too.

Comment: @FariborzGhavamian Answer modified. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It does, thanks @Andrea!

Just a tiny modification. I had to change .replace(b'\x00',b''))) to .replace('\x00',''))).